# save records from WCF service in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data, sqlite, sudzc

I am new to iOS development and CoreData too. I am calling a .Net WCF service for displaying data in a UITableViewcontroller in my app.I am saving this data in CoreData. When I add a new record on the server,I want it to get displayed in the UITableViewController as well as saved in CoreData.But this doesnt happen.I have to do a "Reset Contents and Settings" on the Simulator and then run the application again. When I do this,the app displays  the latest records from the service.It also saves the new record in CoreData.I am using SUDZC for interacting with the wcf service.The code for calling the service,displaying data in UITableViewController and saving it to CoreData looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];

    [my_table setDataSource:self];
    [my_table setDelegate:self];

     EDViPadDocSyncService *service = [[EDViPadDocSyncService alloc]init];
     [service getAllCategories:self action:@selector(handleGetAllCategories:)];

}

-(void)handleGetAllCategories:(id)value
{
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"This is an error %@",value);
        return;
    }

    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"this is a soap fault %@",value);
        return;
    }
    NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray*)value;

    self.myData = [[NSMutableArray array] init];//array for storing 'category name'
    self.catId = [[NSMutableArray array]init];//array for storing 'category ID'    

    self.myData=[self getCategories];

    /*store data in Core Data - START*/
    NSMutableArray *coreDataCategoryarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Categories *newCategory;//this is the CoreData 'Category' object
    for(int j=0;j<[result count];j++)
    {
        EDVCategory *edvCat = [[EDVCategory alloc]init];//this is the SUDZC 'Category' object
        edvCat = [result objectAtIndex:j];

        if ([self.catId count]>0) {
                for (int i=0; i<[self.catId count]; i++) {

                    if ([edvCat categoryId] == [[self.catId objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]) {
                        checkFlag=TRUE;
                    }
                }
        }
        if (checkFlag == FALSE) {
            newCategory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [newCategory setCategoryId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[edvCat categoryId]]];
            [newCategory setCategoryName:edvCat.categoryName];
            [newCategory setDocCount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[edvCat docCount]]];
            [newCategory setCategoryType:[NSNumber numberWithShort:[edvCat categoryType]]];
            [newCategory setSubCategoryId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[edvCat subCategoryId]]];
            [coreDataCategoryarray addObject:newCategory];
        }
    }
    /*store data in Core Data - END*/

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        [coreDataCategoryarray release];
    }
    else
    {
        //return [coreDataCategoryarray autorelease];
        [coreDataCategoryarray autorelease];
    }
    self.myData=[self getCategories];
    [my_table reloadData]; 
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getCategories
{
    NSFetchRequest  *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"categoryId" ascending:YES] autorelease];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];

    [request setEntity:entity];
    entity = nil;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *fetchResults = [[__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    NSManagedObject *aTabrss;
    NSMutableArray *arForGetCategory=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (aTabrss in fetchResults){
        [arForGetCategory addObject:[aTabrss valueForKey:@"categoryName"]];
        [self.catId addObject:[aTabrss valueForKey:@"categoryId"]];
    }
    return (arForGetCategory);
}
```

What changes should I make in my code so that it reflects the latest data from the service and saves it to CoreData(sqlite) at the same time?

Comment: This seems vastly more complex than I would imagine it requires.  Therein may be the problem.  My recommendation would be to look into `NSFetchedResultsController` so at least you would have fewer arrays of managed objects getting passed around.  Here's a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) on `NSFetchedResultsController` that may be helpful.

Comment: @alanduncan :- Thanks for your help.I am using NSFetchRequest.How is it different from NSFetchedResultsController?Aren't they used for fetching data from the database?As I said,I am very new to CoreData and the iOS development and finding it difficult to understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the class that you really need is NSUserDefaults:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I read the documentation about NSUserDefaults.I think it is used for storing the preferences of a user.My requirement is little different from that.I want to synchronise the data on server with the data on the device.Is there anything else I should be looking at?